# Let $f \in C [a,b]$ such that $\forall x\exists y$ such that $|f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$. Prove that $\exists c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

$$f\in C[a,b] $$If given that for every $x\in[a,b]\text{ there exists } y\in[a,b]$ such that:
$$|f(y)| \le \frac{1}{2}|f(x)| $$
Prove that there exists $ c\in[a,b]$ such that :

$$f(c)=0$$

***What I've done so far :***
We will build a sequence in this way:
$$\text{take } x_1\in[a,b]$$
for this $x_1$ there exists $y_1$ such that $ |f(y_1)|\le\frac{1}{2}|f(x_1)|$
$$\text{now $y_1$ will be our $x_2$, } y_1=x_2 $$
we will go on by doing this:
$$\text{take } x_n\in[a,b]$$
for this $x_n$ there exists $y_n$ such that $ |f(y_n)|\le\frac{1}{2}|f(x_n)|\le \frac{1}{2^{n}}|f(x_1)|$

**I know that this is the only way to prove it but can't seem to get on from here.. any help?**

Comment: Now let $n \to +\infty$ and use continuity of $f$ and closedness of $[a,b]$ to conclude that $$|f(\lim y_n)|=\lim|f(y_n)|\le \lim \frac{1}{2^n}f(y_1)=0$$

Comment: Is your function continuous?

Comment: @Jonas Yes. Forgot to mention that. edited

Comment: Then Jimmy R. already replied. Otherwise there would be a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have constructed a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in $[a,b]$ with the property that $$|f(x_n)|\leq \frac{1}{2}|f(x_{n-1})|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|f(x_1)|$$for all $n\geq 1$. Now because $[a,b]$ is compact, it has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\geq 1}$ which converges to $c\in [a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous,$$|f(c)|=\lim_{k\to \infty}|f\left(x_{n_k}\right)|\leq \lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^{n_k}}|f(x_{1})|=0,$$thus $f(c)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $a_n = f(x_n)$, with $x_n$ just as you defined it.

Now let $L = \sup_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)$. We have:

$|f(x_n)| \leq \frac{L}{2^n}$. As $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $|f(c)| \leq0$ .

Comment: Where does the $c$ come from? You should mention that "by the compactness of $[a,b]$" explicitly. Otherwise, the statement is false. For example, let $f:(0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x$. Then there is no such $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.